# How to recover an user account with a specific email address in Ruby ( User Devise Gem use )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

I'm here to ask how to recover an user account that happened to be deleted ( as a mistake ). The user's email address was 'sungpah+100@gmail.com' for instance and want to use this email address again as an account.

I tried to make a new user and insert the same email address but the console output is

User Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'sungpah+100@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK

Can I make an account with 'sungpah+100@gmail.com' again?

When I tried to search the account with the command : User.find_by(:email => 'sungpah+1@gmail.com', the result is nil currently!

The id was 950 and now if I search with User.find(950), ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=950 [WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL]
is the outcome!

Looking forward to seeing any response!
Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to be certain without more information, but from the `deleted_at` query in your question, you appear to be using a gem such as [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) which lets you hide and restore records without deleting them. So that's good!

Try `user = User.unscoped.find(950)`.

You likely have a default scope applied to your User model provided by this `acts_as_paranoid` gem which filters out any record where `deleted_as` is present.  `unscoped` will remove that scope and let you find all records.

Once you've found the user, you can restore it by deleting the `deleted_at` field.

```
user.update_attributes(deleted_at: nil)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks Chrismanderson. When I commanded, I got this message: SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 950 LIMIT 1

Comment: and user information was returned. But after then I tried to find this user with this command: User.find(950),  I got "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=950 [WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL]
" message, which is the same with what I had above. Would you give me any hint to move forward (: ?

Comment: You need to then empty out the `deleted_at` field, added instructions to my answer.